# Conky not working in Gnome 3.4

Tags: gnome, conky

I've installed conky using `sudo apt-get install conky-all` and followed this [tutorial](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-conky-lua-in-ubuntu-11-10-12-04-fedora-debian-and-linuxmint-howto-conky/) to configure. The configuration works properly in Unity desktop in Ubuntu 12.04 and everything seems OK, However using Gnome 3 nothing appears on the desktop.
I have used following command to invoke conky at startup `sh -c "sleep 20s; conky -c ~/.conkyrc"`.

Please suggest what additional steps need to be taken in order to make it work in Gnome shell Ubuntu 12.04.

Here is the [.conkyrc](http://pastebin.com/Nvp044Gb) file.

Comment: Did u give the command from a terminal or in the startup applications ? If starting from terminal, do you get any error ?

Comment: No, i am not getting any kind of error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just replace `own_window_type override` with following lines:

```
own_window_type normal
own_window_argb_visual yes
```

and use following command to start conky automatically at startup:

```
bash -c "sleep 20; conky"
```

Comment: it mostly works. The only problem I have is that hitting Ctrl-Alt-D (the Show Desktop shortcut) hides the conky window too.

Comment: I solved that by using "own_window no" instead of yes. But as fixed it by just trying some different configurations and seeing which worked for me, there may be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

I created a little script that runs conky delayed. I'm not sure why, but there is some kind of problems by running it just when the computer starts.
So create a script (hidden in your home folder, in this case) with

```
gedit ~/.conkystart.sh
```

then add:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30; conky
exit
```

and give it the **execute** permissions

```
chmod +x ~/.conkystart.sh
```

as you can see what the script does is only starts conky after sleeping (waiting) 30 seconds

Now go to the startup application and add this script instead of conky itself

[image: conky autostart setup]

Now restart (or logout and login) ubuntu and wait for 30 seconds. Does it shows up now?

Comment: I updated my conky to 1.9.0 and it works well now.

Answer (score 3):

What you need script for? Just launch it like this by adding to Startup list.

```
conky -p 20 -c /home/{username}/.conkyrc
```

Comment: or conky -p 20 -c ~/.conkyrc ;)

Answer (score 1):

try some of these parameters, specially the own_window_type:

```
update_interval 3
total_run_times 0
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager
double_buffer yes
....
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no
```

Also, I had problems when starting conky at login in an automatically way, so now, I am used to run conky manually. When you try this way do you still have the problem?

Comment: If you have trouble with conky autostarting, it might be because you need to wait until the desktop environment finishes loading.  Have you tried autostarting something like `sleep 3 && conky -d`?

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem too, i think you are trying to use conky-colors. The answer of Basharat Sial is almost there.

My conky-colors configuration was:

`./conky-colors --lang=english --theme=blue --cpu=4 --swap --updates --proc=3 --clock=modern --nvidia --calendar --network --ubuntu`

I have to remove the *--ubuntu* and when asked "Ubuntu/Debian distro?" say n (or press Enter).

After that, create a startup application with this command:

`bash -c "sleep 20; conky -c ~/.conkycolors/conkyrc"`