# Conky Autostart Problem

Tags: autostart, conky

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conky not working in Gnome 3.4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139722/conky-not-working-in-gnome-3-4)

I am using Ubuntu12.04 with gnome3.4. I installed conky to display my system information. And everything is good except that conky can't autostart when the system starts. I have *configure gnome-session-properties* with */usr/share/conkycolors/bin/conkyStart* but it doesn't work. So how can I have my conky autostart? Thank you.