# Conky in Gnome 3.10 Shell

Tags: gnome, 13.10, conky

I have asked this question over on SuperUser but figured since the question is more Ubuntu-centric I should ask it here as well.

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 and recently installed gnome 3.10 on my HPnc6320. I have the 5.2 lua interpreter installed as well and conky. Both from the ubuntu apt-get tool.

I was following the Conky tutorial from [Unix Men](http://www.unixmen.com/configure-conky-lua-in-ubuntu-11-10-12-04-fedora-debian-and-linuxmint-howto-conky/)

I followed every step. I chose the Ubuntu set of Conky and Lua scripts. I put them in the locations and changed the files like it said.

I also changed a parameter in /etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf as outlined [HERE](http://www.ihermit.net/index.php?itemid=30)because I was getting an error about reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated. This changed fixed that as far as I can tell.

Where I am having trouble is when I run Conky, the output I get is:

```
jesse@nc6320 ~:$ conky
Conky: desktop window (100001d) is subwindow of root window (7f)
Conky: window type - override
Conky: drawing to created window (0x4200001)
Conky: drawing to double buffer
```

I am new to Conky and Gnome. What do I have to do to get this Conky script working?

Thank you for any input

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139722/conky-not-working-in-gnome-3-4?rq=1)

I made some changes to the window parameters they are now:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_argb_visual yes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below
```

own_window_type was override and I added the own_window_arb_visual yes parameter

Hope this helps anyone else out

Comment: Thanks, this has helped me.  For a long time (since upgrading from 12.04 LTS), I have had issues with using Conky in fallback mode.

Comment: With your parameter advice and some slight modifications, my conky now stays on desktop. Before (having set own_window_type to 'desktop') it disappeared as soon as I clicked on the background. Solution was to change the window type to normal and to undecorate window hints:
    own_window_type = 'normal',    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',